# Defining a type alias using nested generic parameters

Tags: typescript, types

I'd like to be able to define a type that takes in a generic parameter (that itself extends a type with 2 generic parameters) and define its constraints by using the nested generic parameters.

```
// Boiler plate for example setup:
type NodeCallback<T> = (err?: Error | void, result?: T) => void
type Handler<I, R> = (event: I, callback: NodeCallback<R>) => void
type StrToNumHandler = Handler<string, number>

// I end up having to do this:
type WorkaroundAsyncHandler<T extends Handler<I, R>, I, R> = (event: I) => Promise<R>
type WorkaroundStrToNumHandler = WorkaroundAsyncHandler<StrToNumHandler, string, number>

// I'd like to be able to just write this:
type AsyncHandler<T extends Handler<I, R>> = (event: I) => Promise<R> // This is a compiler error. Not sure how to write this in a valid way.
type AsyncStrToNumHandler = AsyncHandler<StrToNumHandler> // This is the line I'd ultimately like to write
```

The workaround I have compiles, but if I'm supplying the values for `I` and `R`, there isn't any value in supplying the `Handler`, which I'd like to be able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get pretty close with c[onditional types and type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)

```
type AsyncHandler<T> = T extends Handler<infer I, infer R> ? 
                             (event: I) => Promise<R> 
                          :  never
;

type AsyncStrToNumHandler = AsyncHandler<StrToNumHandler> 
// inferred as AsyncStrToNumHandler = (event: string) => Promise<number>
```

The downside is that your type alias should provide some type even if `T` is not actually `Handler`. The usual solution is to return `never` type. But the code that uses such alias can behave unexpectedly at compile time when it receives `never` type.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Would this be solvable by adding an intersection of a non-never type? I expect that would strictly make any `T` that does not extend `Handler` a compilation error instead of propagating a `never` type along.